# Trying to show color swatches in a list of colors

Tags: swift, swiftui, colors

I've got this array:

```
@Published var availableWebCompatibleColors = ["Aqua","Blue","MediumBlue","DarkBlue","BurlyWood","LightSteelBlue","Cyan","Green","Lime","Red","Maroon","Salmon","Yellow","LightYellow","Gold","Gray","LightGray","LightSlateGray","Linen","Purple","Red","White","Black"]
```

And I'm trying to get them to show up as color swatches in a list inside of a form. I've been using this:

```
Picker("Font color", selection: $thePreferences.currentPrefs.libCompViewerBodyColor){
                  ForEach(currentSkin.availableWebCompatibleColors, id: \.self){ i in
                     HStack {
                        Image(systemName:"square.fill")
                           .foregroundColor(Color(i))
                        Text(i)
                     }
                  }
               }
```

But the swatches are just showing up as gray. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Yes, and I've been using them in other places.

Comment: try using `.foregroundStyle(Color(i), Color(i))` instead of `.foregroundColor(Color(i))`

Comment: That works! Thank you workingdog! This has been on my list for a while!